# Firebird RDBMS on Windows embedded compact 7? Alternatives?

Tags: performance, embedded, rdbms, firebird

I need some advice from you. How would you judge running an firebird DBMS on a Windows embedded compact 7 machine?

What about ressources? Any other lightweight easy-to-use alternatives for embedded systems?

thanks for your advice!

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/  it looks like it's supported here http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was very pleased running Firebird years ago on just 200MHz Pentium Windows, so I don't see why it shouldn't run smooth on modern embedded hardware. It all depends on your data. Firebird is also nice for it's almost zero administration need, and if you use Delphi/Lazarus/FPC then it can be also embedded in your application.